# How to find if any column in an array has duplicate values

Tags: numpy

Let's say I have a numpy matrix `A`

```
A = array([[ 0.5,  0.5,  3.7],
           [ 3.8,  2.7,  3.7],
           [ 3.3,  1.0,  0.2]])
```

I would like to know if there is at least two rows `i` and `i'` such that `A[i, j]=A[i', j]` for some column `j`?

In the example `A`, `i=0` and `i'=1` for `j=2` and the answer is `yes`.

How can I do this?

I tried this:

```
def test(A, n):
    for j in range(n):
        i = 0
        while i < n:
            a = A[i, j]
            for s in range(i+1, n):
                if A[s, j] == a:
                    return True
            i += 1
    return False
```

Is there a faster/better way?

Comment: Are you looking to see if there is any column that contains a repeated element?

Comment: Because A) That is much easier to understand, and B) yes, you can make it much faster.

Comment: Be careful when testing for `==` with floats.  It's not as predictable as with integers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a number of ways of checking for duplicates. The idea is to use as few loops in the Python code as possible to do this. I will present a couple of ways here:

1. Use [`np.unique`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/reference/generated/numpy.unique.html). You would still have to loop over the columns since it wouldn't make sense for `unique` to accept an `axis` argument because each column could have a different number of unique elements. While it still requires a loop, `unique` allows you to find the positions and other stats of repeated elements:

   ```
   def test(A):
       for i in range(A.shape[1]):
           if np.unique(A[:, i]).size < A.shape[0]:
               return True
       return False
   ```

   With this method, you basically check if the number of unique elements in a column is equal to the size of the column. If not, there are duplicates.
2. Use [`np.sort`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.sort.html), [`np.diff`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/reference/generated/numpy.diff.html) and [`np.any`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.any.html). This is a fully vectorized solution that does not require any loops because you can specify an axis for each of these functions:

   ```
   def test(A):
       return np.any(diff(np.sort(A, axis=0), axis=0) == 0)
   ```

   This literally reads "if any of the column-wise differences in the column-wise sorted array are zero, return True". A zero difference in the sorted array means that there are identical elements. `axis=0` makes `sort` and `diff` operate on each column individually.

You never need to pass in `n` since the size of the matrix is encoded in the attribute `shape`. If you need to look at the subset of a matrix, just pass in the subset using indexing. It will not copy the data, just return a view object with the required dimensions.

Answer (score 1):

A solution without numpy would look like this: First, swap columns and rows with `zip()`

```
zipped = zip(*A)
```

then check if any *now row* has any duplicates. You can check for duplicates by turning a list into a set, which discards duplicates, and check the length.

```
has_duplicates = any(len(set(row)) != len(row) for row in zip(*A))
```

Most probably way slower and also more memory intensive than the pure numpy solution, but this may help for clarity